# Xamarin throw error : No view found for id 0x1 (unknown) for fragment ShellItemRenderer{...} I am trying to add ads to my application using AdMob

Tags: xml, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.forms, admob

I am trying to add advertisements to my application using admob, but I am getting this error after running the application: "Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'No view found for id 0x1 (unknown) for fragment ShellItemRenderer{...}...

OnCreate in MainActivity.cs :

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            FFImageLoading.Forms.Platform.CachedImageRenderer.Init(true);
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext);
            string adUnitId = Resources.GetString(Resource.String.banner_ad_unit_id);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            AdView adView = FindViewById<AdView>(Resource.Id.adView);
            var adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
            adView.LoadAd(adRequest);

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-***" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What's problem?

Can you help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you posted,I found that you are trying to use the `AdView` in your xamarin android project, but your app is a xamarin form app. So, you should be confused with the method of use.

**For xamarin android**

For how to add adview in **xamarin android**, you can check the [AdMobExample Sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/main/google-services/AdMobExample) here. This sample demonstrates how to display different types of ads using `Google AdMob` with `Google Play Services`.

**For xamarin form**

On xamarin form, the steps to add admob to app are as follows:

- Adding required packages.

  For Android,Add `Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads` package.

  For iOS,Add `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.AdMob` Package
- Changes to be done in Manifest.xml file(only for Android)
- Creating `Custom Renders` to access Ads for Banner type Ads
- Accessing `Custom Renders` in the code to display Banner type Ads.
- Creating `Dependency Services` to access Ads for Interstitial type Ads.
- Accessing `Dependency Services` in the code to display Interstitial
  type Ads.

For more information,you can check article [Google AdMob - Display Ads In Xamarin Forms](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/google-admob-display-ads-in-xamarin-forms/)

and  [AdMob In Xamarin.Forms – Display Google Ads In Your Mobile App](https://www.xamarinhelp.com/admob-xamarin-forms-display-google-ads-mobile-app/).

You can get an example here [Adview sample of xamarin forms](https://github.com/adamped/AdMob).